# How to wait for process to write to a file or exit?

Tags: linux, sh, inotify, waitpid

I need to monitor a process -- with a known PID -- and react to it *either* exiting for good, or writing into a file in a known subdirectory.

The file(s) may not initially exist. On BSD I would use `kqueue` specifying the different things I want to be woken up for. But this program is for Linux.

I know, inotify can advise me of new files created or existing files opened/closed in a directory. But it will not tell me about the process exiting...

How do I watch for all of these events? Ideally, this would be done in shell, but I could compile a helper C-program, which the shell-script would call...

Comment: If the process exit()s, the file will be closed anyhow. /caseclosed

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to be notified of a process exiting (except for children of the current process, the parent receives a SIGCHLD signal). I think the only solution is periodically testing if the PID exists.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but maybe adding watching for `/proc/NNNN` to be deleted, where `NNNN` is the process's pid, to your inotify events?